# Access name of list component via element

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing character vectors of different length (each vector element is unique in the list). I now want to access the name of the component of a list that contains a specific element via this element. To make it clearer, my list looks basically as follows:

```
l <- list(alpha = c("a", "b", "c"), beta = c("x", "y"))
$alpha
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$beta
[1] "x" "y"
```

I now have a dataframe containing the list elements:

```
df = data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c", "x", "y"))
```

Via mutate, I now want to get the name of the list component that contains the respective element, so

```
  name  corr
1    a alpha
2    b alpha
3    c alpha
4    x  beta
5    y  beta
```

I would know how to do this via loop but that is computationally infeasible and also not nice code ;) Does anybody have an idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stack` to get a data.frame

```
stack(l)
```

---

Or using `enframe`

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(l, name = "corr", value = "name") %>% 
   unnest
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  corr  name 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 alpha a    
#2 alpha b    
#3 alpha c    
#4 beta  x    
#5 beta  y
```

#### Update

If we want to get the names of the `list` element from the value of the `list` element given as an argument to a function

```
f1 <- function(lstData, elem) {
     i1 <- sapply(lstData, function(x) elem %in% x)
     names(lstData[i1])
 }

f1(l, "x")
#[1] "beta"
```

Or after converting to `data.frame/tibble` as earlier, `filter` and then `pull` the values in the 'name' column

```
f2 <- function(lstData, elem) {
    tibble::enframe(lstData, name = "corr", value = "name") %>%
        tidyr::unnest(.) %>%
        dplyr::filter(name == elem) %>%
        dplyr::pull(corr)
  }

f2(l, 'x')
#[1] "beta"
```

Comment: Thanks so far, I maybe should have been more precise - I basically want a function where the input is the element (e.g. "x") and the output is the name of the list component that contains it. So in this case input "x" and output "beta"